# Designing a timer-triggered processor which relies on data from events

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-functions, azure-storage, system-design

I am trying to design a **timer-triggered processor (all in azure) which will process a set of records that are set out for it to be consumed.** It will be grouping it based on a column, creating files out of it, and dumping in a blob container. The records that it will consume are supposed to be generated based on an event - when the event is raised, containing a key, which can be used to query the data for the record (the data/ record being generated is to be pulled from different services.)

This is what I am thinking currently

> 1. Event is raised to event-grid-topic
> 2. Azure Function(ConsumerApp) is event triggered, reads the key, calls a service API to get all the data, stores that record in storage
>    table, with flag ready to be consumed.
> 3. Azure Function(ProcessorApp) is timer triggered, will read from the storage table, group based on another column, create and dump them as
>    files. This can then mark the records as processed, if not updated
>    already by ConsumerApp.

Some of my questions on these, apart from any way we can do it in a different better way are -

1. The table storage is going to fill up quickly, which will again decrease the speed to read the 'ready cases' so is there any better approach to store this intermediate & temporary data? One thing which I thought was to regularly flush the table or delete the record from the consumer app instead of marking it as 'processed'
2. The service API is being called for each event, which might increase the strain on that service/its database. should I group the call for records as a single API call, since the processor will run only after a said interval, or is there a better approach here?

Any feedback on this approach or a new design will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have to process data on Step 2 individually, you can try saving it in a blob too and add a record the blob path in Azure Table Storage to keep minimal row count.
2. Azure Table Storage has partitions that you can use to partition your data and keep your read operations fast. Partition scan is faster compared to table scan. In addition, Azure Table Storage is cheap, but if you have pricing concern. Then you can write a clean up function to periodically clean the processed rows. Keeping the processed rows around for a reasonable time is usually a good idea. Because you may need those for debugging issues.
3. By batching multiple calls in a single call, you can decrease network I/O delay. But resource contention will remain at service level. You can try moving that API to a separate service if possible to scale it separately.